# Turn based multiplayer for iOS using CouchDB and IrisCouch

Tags: javascript, ios, nosql, couchdb

Me and my startup app company is working on a turn based multiplayer iPhone application. Let it be said that neither one of us have any database, or server, knowledge whatsoever. Though, we are willing to learn.

The flow of the game will be similar to such games as: WordFeud, WordsWithFriends, Rumble etc.

Let me start of by where a lot of searching on the web has gotten us:

We have decided to use [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) as a tool for storing information about users, game sessions and other stuff. CouchDB is an open source noSQL database system. The reason is that we have been taught, that it should support a lot off concurring users. Besides, that it scales - we are hoping to go big, of course.

Our CouchDB, is hosted on [IrisCouch](http://www.iriscouch.com/). IrisCouch is an "in cloud" hosting service designed for running CouchDb.

So, we've got a CouchDB server up and running, and we know the basics on how to query data from the server.

Our biggest confusion right now, is how we should set up the system to work according to best practices. Right now we are at the point where we are able to receive and submit data to the server.

Our game is supposed to have Facebook integration, so that the users can register via our app or through Facebook. After that they can play with random matched opponents, or play with friends. After a match is started, one player will get a set of question to be asked, after he has answered, the other player should be notified, through push notification, that it's their turn. After a few rounds the game is finished.

At this point, we think this might be the best solution for the flow of the application:

1. A user connects to another user -> a game session is opened as a
   document in a database called "games".
2. The newly created document contains both player names, question,
   answers etc
3. A field named "whos_turn" decides which of the two players turn it is.
4. After the game has ended, the session is erased.

Again, and as you may see, we are in the dark as of how to really do it, but this is the general idea.

So, my questions goes as following:

**Is it best to query the data directly from the iPhone application, or through a web service?**

**What is the best way to set up the database, to best manage the flow of the application?**

Any information, that could lead us closer will be gladly appreciated :)

In advance, thank you!

Olav Gundersen

---

**EDIT#1 : Our Objective-C programmer managed to connect two iPhone devices using CouchDb. The iPhone application consists of a table view, that has a concurrent connection with the database, so that when someone POST to the database, it shows up on the tableview of all the other connected phones. Behold: a severely ineffective chat system.**

Answer (score 5):

If is a multiplayer you would need to have the app to communicate to the remote iriscouch.db but I am concerned by the point where you state that neither you or your friends have any database experience. You are willing to learn so I think the best place to start is:

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/index.html

There are several issue you might find with scalability if you plan to erase documents continuously. DB Size can be considerable on couchdb and you will need to compact &cleanup the db regularly. But I don't think is a major issue for now as this is at a start up level.

The question *"best way to setup the database and best manage the flow of the application"* should be addressed by your team. If you do not have someone with *any* database experience you should try to find someone willing to help you. It should be someone with extensive experience in databases. You might find some fairly reasonable professionals at http://www.odesk.com

In total honestly I don't think you will be successful if you don't have such a figure - either as a freelancer or contributor - to help you having a solid database logic in the game that will ensure a great user experience.

For example: have you considered the latency-delay issue by using a db based in the USA (Iriscouch) vs. where your users are located?

For this reason you might want to do as much as possible client side (embedded database like sqlite or touchDB that is essentially couchDB for iPhone)

For an iPhone application you might want to try TouchDB that is made exactly for that
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS (caveat: being that you need connectivity to check turns etc this might not be the ideal solution but it could work to store some information locally).

To lay this out you would need someone with experience with couchdb to set up a proper, usable application. There is nothing wrong in being enthusiast about your idea but to make it a success you need a technical mind in the database side. Of course you might be well capable to learn this yourself. After reading the CouchDB book you should be in position to create a basic flow to fit your needs.

Of course other more experienced users might come with a more comprehensive answer or a sample layout but I don't think would be the best approach. Even if someone posts a full layout of the doc structure and how to query it how are you going to service the app if something goes awry  e.g. sessions don't get deleted, conflicts etc. ? hence my sincere advice to get some ad-hoc expertise for your case.

This might also result in analyzing suitable alternatives. I don't think you should buy into the idea that CouchDB can scale and hence is the best/only option for you (of course this might well be the case and if you feel that is a good option..go for it). For example twitter, google adwords and many other online apps are using mysql to store their data so for sure CouchDB is not the only database that can scale!

Comment: Wow! Thank you for posting such an extensive answer! I know, we are fumbling in the dark, and we are aware that this process may be long, and that we have to learn a lot of new technologies, but we are determined to make it a success. I will read through the CouchDb, and try to decide if our solution is most suited for a relational db system, or a noSQL system. Will post back with what i find. If we post everything we learn on the way in this thread, I am sure it will help a lot of people, even though it doesn't solve our problem in particular :)

Comment: you are welcome :) I wish you the best of luck. Keep doing some connection tests like the one in your update. Perhaps you will hit some speed limitations and this might be a sign that you need to rethink the way it works. You should also read about other similar apps and investigate what they use - don't be afraid to take "inspiration" from good and established apps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this demo app could be a good example to follow: [iOS Couchbase Demo](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iOS-Couchbase-Demo)